# Grouping based on two elements (surname and firstname) even if surname contains entities

Tags: xslt

Suggest for how to group the Index entries based on **surname** and **firstname** (some times surname may starts with entity like **&Racute;**, then those surname should be sorted in **R** series). My code is unable to give element name for surname and firstname. (XSLT ver 2)

- How to insert tag (element) <surname> and <firstname> for author Content.

For sorting based on entities see earlier suggestion [See link for Sorting Author names even for Entities also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889002/xslt-sorting-authors-based-on-surnames-and-based-on-charmap-character-also).

Input XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE index [<!ENTITY Racute "&#x00154;">]>
 <index>
 <cmindexnote>This index is cumulative for volume 65</cmindexnote>
<issue>v65n</issue>
<author>
  <lastname>Rudramuni</lastname>
  <firstname>TP</firstname>
  <refserial>
    <serno>14</serno>
  </refserial>
</author>
<author>
  <lastname>Rudramuni</lastname>
  <firstname>CP</firstname>
  <refserial>
    <serno>14</serno>
  </refserial>
</author>
<author>
  <lastname>Rudramuni</lastname>
  <firstname>TP</firstname>
  <refserial>
    <serno>10</serno>
  </refserial>
</author>
 <author>
  <lastname>Rudramuni</lastname>
  <firstname>TP</firstname>
  <refserial>
    <serno>11</serno>
  </refserial>
</author>

<author>
  <lastname>Rudresh</lastname><firstname>TP</firstname>
  <refserial>
    <serno>11</serno>
  </refserial>
</author>
<author>
  <lastname>&Racute;udramuni</lastname>
  <firstname>TP</firstname>
  <refserial>
    <serno>11</serno>
  </refserial>
</author>
</index>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" use-character-maps="chars"/>
    <xsl:character-map name="chars">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#x00154;" string="&amp;Racute;"/>
    </xsl:character-map>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="index">
      <cmindexnote><xsl:value-of select="cmindexnote"/></cmindexnote>
      <issue><xsl:value-of select="issue"/></issue>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="author" group-by="concat(lastname, firstname)">
          <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?lang=en&amp;ignore-modifiers=yes"/>
                <author><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:sort select="refserial/serno"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </author>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="author">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except (lastname, firstname)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required Result:

```
<index>
<cmindexnote>This index is cumulative for volume 65</cmindexnote><issue>v65n</issue>
 <author>
   <lastname>Rudramuni</lastname><firstname>CP</firstname>
    <refserial>
      <serno>14</serno>
    </refserial>
 </author>
 <author>
   <lastname>Rudramuni</lastname><firstname>TP</firstname>
   <refserial>
     <serno>10</serno>
   </refserial>
   <refserial>
     <serno>11</serno>
   </refserial>
   <refserial>
     <serno>14</serno>
   </refserial>
</author>
<author>
  <lastname>&Racute;udramuni</lastname><firstname>TP</firstname>
  <refserial>
    <serno>11</serno>
  </refserial>
</author>
<author>
  <lastname>Rudresh</lastname><firstname>TP</firstname>
  <refserial>
    <serno>11</serno>
  </refserial>
</author>
<author>
</index>
```

Comment: Is the entity `Racute` that is referenced by `&Racute;` not declared in your input XML? In that case parsing it with an XML parser will simply give an error and we will never get to the point of sorting it with XSLT.

Comment: One request, can I change &Racute; to &amp;Racute;, in this case sorting will work. Please suggest.

Comment: @Martin Honnen, can I change &Racute; to &#x00154; (UNICODE).

Comment: You can certainly use a character reference in XML, yes. Of course entity references are also allowd, but only if the entity is declared earlier in the DOCTYPE.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I updated input XML, now how to get the '&Racute' only in output file.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Now I updated XSLT also, now I am getting &Racute; in output XML, now requirement is <surname> and <lastname> tags required for the author content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got the answer, please check whether this OK or not.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" use-character-maps="chars"/>
<xsl:include href="Unicode.xsl"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="index">
      <cmindexnote><xsl:value-of select="cmindexnote"/></cmindexnote>
      <issue><xsl:value-of select="issue"/></issue>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="author" group-by="concat(lastname, firstname)">
        <xsl:sort select="lastname" collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?lang=en&amp;ignore-modifiers=yes"/>  
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?lang=en&amp;ignore-modifiers=yes"/>
                <author>
                    <lastname><xsl:value-of select="*[1]"/></lastname>
                    <firstname><xsl:value-of select="*[2]"/></firstname>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:sort select="number(refserial/serno)"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </author>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="author">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except (lastname, firstname)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

CharMap XSLT (Unicode.xsl):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:character-map name="chars">
<xsl:output-character character="&#x00154;" string="&amp;Racute;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```